# How to add a simple preferences screen to an android input method editor app

Tags: java, android, xml, settings, ime

I've been working on a fairly simple keyboard application and I wanted to add a few settings to it. I've been through several tutorials and more reference pages than I can count over the last week and I was hoping someone here might be able/willing to catch my mistake(s).

My app builds without error (only a single warning about the use of a depreciated function, ) but the preferences activity just will not launch from the language and input settings menu.

Heres what I have so far

Contents of the application tag on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
    android:name=".SimpleIME"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.view.im"
        android:resource="@xml/method" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<activity
    android:name=".keyboardPrefsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_keyboard_prefs">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

method.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/subtype_en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard"
        android:settingsActivity="com.dev.tompk.learnmorsekeyboard.keyboardPrefsActivity"/>
</input-method>
```

preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="lmk_settings"
    android:title="Learn Morse Keyboard Settings">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="MorsePulseRate"
        android:title="@string/morse_pulse_rate_pref_title"
        android:summary="@string/morse_pulse_rate_pref_summary"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:defaultValue="100"
        />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

keyboardPrefsActivity.java

```
package com.dev.tompk.learnmorsekeyboard;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class keyboardPrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private EditTextPreference morsePulseRate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        morsePulseRate = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("MorsePulseRate");
    }
}
```

At this point I don't need anything fancy with headers or breaking it out into smaller fragments (unless that's necessary to make it work). My current aim is to have a list of 2 maybe 3 settings each taking an integer (string will do if necessary since it can be converted or replaced with a default value)

I realize my code is a bit messy with all of the different things I've tried, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I realize that this answer might be a bit late for you, but someone might want the answer to this. Try adding an 'android:theme=""' to the settings activity like you would a normal activity, that solved the problem for me.

Also you can try putting the 'android:settingsActivity' inside the input-method tag rather than under the subtype tag.

Comment: Declaring activity in input-method tag solved it for me, tnx